# No key is attached while writing the secret to vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I am trying to write a vault secret which is a file.

```latex
PS C:\workspace> vault kv put -address=https://someserver.com -namespace=somenamespace secret/runtime/other/dev value="@test.pwd"
Key                Value
---                -----
created_time       2022-08-22T06:54:50.018110723Z
custom_metadata    <nil>
deletion_time      n/a
destroyed          false
version            15
PS C:\workspace> vault kv get -address=https://someserver.com -namespace=somenamespace secret/runtime/other/dev
======= Metadata =======
Key                Value
---                -----
created_time       2022-08-22T06:54:50.018110723Z
custom_metadata    <nil>
deletion_time      n/a
destroyed          false
version            15

== Data ==
Key    Value
---    -----
:�<↕zMn�L��T2���홆j����?Н�xil܉
```

The file is getting stored to vault but the key is null. Is there a way to to attached any key also to it.

Comment: In your case, the key should be "value" and the value should be the contents of the file "test.pwd". I couldn't understand why it didn't work as expected. Is the test.pwd a binary file? Have you tried to use a text one?

Comment: try to use `value="$(cat test.pwd)"`

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can't reproduce in `-dev` mode with Vault 1.11.0 on Linux. Please add the result of `vault version` and `xxd test.pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

That is just bad luck. The file `test.pwd` probably happens to have a carriage return (`\r`) in it. When Vault command line displays the secret value, the carriage return is interpreted by the shell and it overwrites the key name, which is `value` in your example.

You can see them both if you output the in JSON format with:

```
vault kv get -format json -address=https://someserver.com -namespace=somenamespace secret/runtime/other/dev
```